# Migrations are pending; depot_g agile web development with rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I need your help.
My Ruby on Rails tutorial(agile web development with rails 4, block g) gives me an error. I am new to Ruby and have no idea how to fix it.

**Source**:

```
class CombineItemsInCart < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def up

      Cart.all.each do |cart|
        # how many goods are in the cart?
        sums = cart.line_items.group(:product_id).sum(:quantity)
        sums.each do |product_id; quantity|
          if quantity > 1
            # remove lines
            cart.line_items.where(:product_id product_id).delete_all

            # replace with a one line
            item = cart.line_items.build(product_id: product_id)
            item.quantity = quantity
            item.save!
          end
       end
    end
  end
end
```

The error is:

> Migrations are pending; run 'rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=development' to
>   resolve this issue.

But when I tried to run **rake db:migrate**,
 I receive this error in terminal:

> rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=development
>
> rake aborted! SyntaxError:
>   /home/yury/Desktop/rails/depot_g/db/migrate/20170401195439_combine_items_in_cart.rb:10:
>   syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting ')'
>               cart.line_items.where(:product_id product_id).delete_all
>                                                           ^ /home/yury/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in
>   `require'
>   /home/yury/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in`
>   block in require'
>   /home/yury/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:213:in
>   `load_dependency'
>   /home/yury/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in`
>   require'
>   /home/yury/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:718:in `load_migration'
>   /home/yury/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:714:in`migration'
>   /home/yury/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:708:in `disable_ddl_transaction'
>   /home/yury/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1012:in`
>   use_transaction?'
>   /home/yury/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1004:in
>   `ddl_transaction'
>   /home/yury/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:958:in`execute_migration_in_transaction'
>   /home/yury/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:920:in `block in migrate'
>   /home/yury/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:916:in`each'
>   /home/yury/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:916:in `migrate'
>   /home/yury/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:764:in`up'
>   /home/yury/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:742:in `migrate'
>   /home/yury/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:42:in`
>   block (2 levels) in '
>   /home/yury/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648/gems/rake-12.0.0/exe/rake:27:in
>   `<top (required)>'
>   /home/yury/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in`
>   eval'
>   /home/yury/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in
>   `' Tasks: TOP => db:migrate (See full trace by running task with
>   --trace)

System: Ubuntu 16.04 64 bit.
I checked the code few times and it is the same as in the book.

So could anyone help me and tell what I am doing wrong? And how can I fix it?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it says "`syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting ')'`" then there's a typo in your code syntax and is in your `sums.each` block, change

```
sums.each do |product_id; quantity|
```

For

```
sums.each do |product_id, quantity|
```

And in your `if` statement from this

```
cart.line_items.where(:product_id product_id)
```

To this

```
cart.line_items.where(product_id: product_id)
```

Check the original code from the book:

```
# rails40/depot_g/db/migrate/20121130000005_combine_items_in_cart.rb
def up
  # replace multiple items for a single product in a cart with a single item
  Cart.all.each do |cart|
    # count the number of each product in the cart
    sums = cart.line_items.group(:product_id).sum(:quantity)
    sums.each do |product_id, quantity|
      if quantity > 1
        # remove individual items
        cart.line_items.where(product_id: product_id).delete_all
        # replace with a single item
        item = cart.line_items.build(product_id: product_id)
        item.quantity = quantity
        item.save!
      end
    end
  end
end
```